# compiling code for 'iWave' Surface simulation by Jerry Tessendorf

Tags: compiler-errors, simulation

I found this code in a paper written about the simulation of fluid surfaces 
http://www-evasion.imag.fr/people/Fabrice.Neyret/images/fluids-nuages/waves/Jonathan/articlesCG/simulating-ocean-water-01.pdf

but when i try to run the code in Dev C++ I get a bunch of compiler errors
like "stray '\146' in program"

The compiler errors were fixed, they were due to the incorrect formatted ' from the pdf.

The code now compiles without error, however when it runs nothing happens at all.

could anyone help me? the code is shown below

```
#include <cmath>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/gl.h> // OpenGL itself.
#include <GL/glu.h> // GLU support library.
#include <GL/glut.h> // GLUT support library.
#endif
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int iwidth, iheight, size;
float *display_map;
float *obstruction;
float *source;
float *height;
float *previous_height;
float *vertical_derivative;
float scaling_factor;
float kernel[13][13];
int paint_mode;
enum{ PAINT_OBSTRUCTION, PAINT_SOURCE };
bool regenerate_data;
bool toggle_animation_on_off;
float dt, alpha, gravity;
float obstruction_brush[3][3];
float source_brush[3][3];
int xmouse_prev, ymouse_prev;
//--------------------------------------------------------
//
// Initialization routines
//
//
// Initialize all of the fields to zero
void Initialize( float *data, int size, float value )
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++ ) { data[i] = value; }
}
// Compute the elements of the convolution kernel
void InitializeKernel()
{
    double dk = 0.01;
    double sigma = 1.0;
    double norm = 0;
    for(double k=0;k<10;k+=dk)
    {
        norm += k*k*exp(-sigma*k*k);
    }
    for( int i=-6;i<=6;i++ )
    {
        for( int j=-6;j<=6;j++ )
        {
            double r = sqrt( (float)(i*i + j*j) );
            double kern = 0;
            for( double k=0;k<10;k+=dk)
            {
                kern += k*k*exp(-sigma*k*k)*j0(r*k);
            }
            kernel[i+6][j+6] = kern / norm;
        }
    }
}
void InitializeBrushes()
{
    obstruction_brush[1][1] = 0.0;
    obstruction_brush[1][0] = 0.5;
    obstruction_brush[0][1] = 0.5;
    obstruction_brush[2][1] = 0.5;
    obstruction_brush[1][2] = 0.5;
    obstruction_brush[0][2] = 0.75;
    obstruction_brush[2][0] = 0.75;
    obstruction_brush[0][0] = 0.75;
    obstruction_brush[2][2] = 0.75;
    source_brush[1][1] = 1.0;
    source_brush[1][0] = 0.5;
    source_brush[0][1] = 0.5;
    source_brush[2][1] = 0.5;
    source_brush[1][2] = 0.5;
    source_brush[0][2] = 0.25;
    source_brush[2][0] = 0.25;
    source_brush[0][0] = 0.25;
    source_brush[2][2] = 0.25;
}
void ClearObstruction()
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++ ){ obstruction[i] = 1.0; }
}
void ClearWaves()
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++ )
    {
        height[i] = 0.0;
        previous_height[i] = 0.0;
        vertical_derivative[i] = 0.0;
    }
}
//----------------------------------------------------
void ConvertToDisplay()
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++ )
    {
        display_map[i] = 0.5*( height[i]/scaling_factor + 1.0 )*obstruction[i];
    }
}
//----------------------------------------------------
//
// These two routines,
//
// ComputeVerticalDerivative()
// Propagate()
//
// are the heart of the iWave algorithm.
//
// In Propagate(), we have not bothered to handle the
// boundary conditions. This makes the outermost
// 6 pixels all the way around act like a hard wall.
//
void ComputeVerticalDerivative()
{
    // first step: the interior
    for(int ix=6;ix<iwidth-6;ix++)
    {
        for(int iy=6;iy<iheight-6;iy++)
        {
            int index = ix + iwidth*iy;
            float vd = 0;
            for(int iix=-6;iix<=6;iix++)
            {
                for(int iiy=-6;iiy<=6;iiy++)
                {
                    int iindex = ix+iix + iwidth*(iy+iiy);
                    vd += kernel[iix+6][iiy+6] * height[iindex];
                }
            }
            vertical_derivative[index] = vd;
        }
    }
}
void Propagate()
{
    // apply obstruction
    for( int i=0;i<size;i++ ) { height[i] *= obstruction[i]; }
    // compute vertical derivative
    ComputeVerticalDerivative();
    // advance surface
    float adt = alpha*dt;
    float adt2 = 1.0/(1.0+adt);
    for( int i=0;i<size;i++ )
    {
        float temp = height[i];
        height[i] = height[i]*(2.0-adt)-previous_height[i]-gravity*vertical_derivative[i];
        height[i] *= adt2;
        height[i] += source[i];
        height[i] *= obstruction[i];
        previous_height[i] = temp;
        // reset source each step
        source[i] = 0;
    }
}
//------------------------------------------
//
// Painting and display code
//
void resetScaleFactor( float amount )
{
    scaling_factor *= amount;
}
void DabSomePaint( int x, int y )
{
    int xstart = x - 1;
    int ystart = y - 1;
    if( xstart < 0 ){ xstart = 0; }
    if( ystart < 0 ){ ystart = 0; }
    int xend = x + 1;
    int yend = y + 1;
    if( xend >= iwidth ){ xend = iwidth-1; }
    if( yend >= iheight ){ yend = iheight-1; }
    if( paint_mode == PAINT_OBSTRUCTION )
    {
        for(int ix=xstart;ix <= xend; ix++)
        {
            for( int iy=ystart;iy<=yend; iy++)
            {
                int index = ix + iwidth*(iheight-iy-1);
                obstruction[index] *= obstruction_brush[ix-xstart][iy-ystart];
            }
        }
    }
    else if( paint_mode == PAINT_SOURCE )
    {
        for(int ix=xstart;ix <= xend; ix++)
        {
            for( int iy=ystart;iy<=yend; iy++)
            {
                int index = ix + iwidth*(iheight-iy-1);
                source[index] += source_brush[ix-xstart][iy-ystart];
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
//----------------------------------------------------
//
// GL and GLUT callbacks
//
//----------------------------------------------------
void cbDisplay( void )
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    glDrawPixels( iwidth, iheight, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_FLOAT, display_map );
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
// animate and display new result
void cbIdle()
{
    if( toggle_animation_on_off ) { Propagate(); }
    ConvertToDisplay();
    cbDisplay();
}
void cbOnKeyboard( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
    switch (key)
    {
    case ’-’: case ’_’:
        resetScaleFactor( 1.0/0.9 );
        regenerate_data = true;
        break;
    case ’+’: case ’=’:
        resetScaleFactor( 0.9 );
        regenerate_data = true;
        break;
    case ’ ’:
        toggle_animation_on_off = !toggle_animation_on_off;
    case ’o’:
        paint_mode = PAINT_OBSTRUCTION;
        break;
    case ’s’:
        paint_mode = PAINT_SOURCE;
        break;
    case ’b’:
        ClearWaves();
        ClearObstruction();
        Initialize( source, size, 0.0 );
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
void cbMouseDown( int button, int state, int x, int y )
{
    if( button != GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON ) { return; }
    if( state != GLUT_DOWN ) { return; }
    xmouse_prev = x;
    ymouse_prev = y;
    DabSomePaint( x, y );
}
void cbMouseMove( int x, int y )
{
    xmouse_prev = x;
    ymouse_prev = y;
    DabSomePaint( x, y );
}
//---------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // initialize a few variables
    iwidth = iheight = 200;
    size = iwidth*iheight;
    dt = 0.03;
    alpha = 0.3;
    gravity = 9.8 * dt * dt;
    scaling_factor = 1.0;
    toggle_animation_on_off = true;
    // allocate space for fields and initialize them
    height = new float[size];
    previous_height = new float[size];
    vertical_derivative = new float[size];
    obstruction = new float[size];
    source = new float[size];
    display_map = new float[size];
    ClearWaves();
    ClearObstruction();
    ConvertToDisplay();
    Initialize( source, size, 0 );
    InitializeBrushes();
    // build the convolution kernel
    InitializeKernel();
    // GLUT routines
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize( iwidth, iheight );
    // Open a window
    char title[] = "iWave Demo";
    int Window_ID = glutCreateWindow( title );
    glClearColor( 1,1,1,1 );
    glutDisplayFunc(&cbDisplay);
    glutIdleFunc(&cbIdle);
    glutKeyboardFunc(&cbOnKeyboard);
    glutMouseFunc( &cbMouseDown );
    glutMotionFunc( &cbMouseMove );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 1;
}; `
```

Comment: Remove the two first characters of the file (the backquote and the space).

Comment: that was just a mistype when i uploaded the code here. thats not in the actual file. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You've copy-pasted code from a PDF which used luxury-quality Unicode quote marks instead of plain old standard quote marks.

Yours:

```
’
```

Everyone else's:

```
'
```

Do a search-and-replace and it should work. It's possible there's other, similarly nice-but-not-ASCII characters you'll have to fix.

Comment: AHH thank you. Its quite late here (1am) will try in the morning and let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: I actually just tried it, and it worked as in there are no compiler errors. However when i run it, nothing happens at all. Can anyone see why?